# Accumulate data for batch updates and send it after passing threshold limits of size or after timed duration?

Tags: java, database, cassandra

Is it a good strategy to accumulate in webserver memory upto a specific limit of data over time that is being written to the database & send it as batch updates after every specified interval or after data grows bigger than threshold size.

Such kind of data would be very small like just adding a relationship between two entities which means adding just a set of ids to the rows.

(Of course, the delayed data should be such that is not expected to be immediately visible).

Are there any disadvantages of this approach ?

---

*Usage: Building web application using Cassandra DB, with Java & JSF.*

Comment: The delay can be small enough that it appears as "immediate" as not adding a delay. i.e. its not possible to have a zero delay, but also not possible for a human to see a small delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: this is a bad idea.

Cassandra's batch operations (e.g. http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/api/pycassa/batch.html) are there to allow you to group updates in an idempotent unit. This allows you to retry the batch as a unit, so the purpose is roughly similar to a transaction in a relational database.

However, unlike the transaction analogy, the impact on performance is negligible and in fact making the load artificially "bursty" is usually counterproductive.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan ! Is there anything similar to `queue_size` for batch operations provided by Hector(to automatically send batch after threshold size)

Comment: And you mean this is a bad idea becasue the client libraries already provide this option through batch mutations, right !?

Comment: No, I mean that if you're trying to batch as an optimization, instead of because a group of operations logically belongs together, then You're Doing It Wrong.  (And if they logically belong together you don't need to worry about queue sizing etc...)

Comment: okay got your point that i should write the data i m getting immediately without waiting & doing updates in batch operations(wrongly assuming  it as an optimization) & if my data needs to be atomic then there are batch operations to take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

The main disadvantage is that it requires another thread to implement the timeout (a small amount of complexity) However the benefits are likely to be much greater.

A simple way to implement this is to use a wait/notify (there doesn't appear to be a good solution using the concurrency library)

```
private final List<T> buffered = new ArrayList<T>();
private final int notifySize = ...
private final int timeoutMS = ...

public synchronized void add(T t) {
    buffered.add(t);
    if (buffered.size() >= notifySize)
       notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void drain(List<T> drained) throws InterruptedException {
    while(buffered.isEmpty())
        wait(timeoutMS);
    drained.addAll(buffered);
    buffered.clear();
}
```

The add and drained can be called by any number of threads, however I imagine you would have only one thread draining, until it is interrupted.

Comment: so since I am using JSF, is it good to accumulate data in the application scoped managed beans on the webserver which then pass after crossing thresholds ? Could you also clarify how much delay in time you consider to be acceptable? (Assume no urgencies for that data by end user)

Comment: That is really up to you. However a typical delay might be 0.5 to 5 seconds. It could be as short as 0.05 seconds, or even longer than 30 seconds. This approach works whether you are using JSF or not.